# Regex Find All Numbers Between 6 or 7 Digits

Tags: python, regex

I am using this regex using the re module in python and getting this result:

```
In [156]: re.findall(r'.*\D(\d{6,7})\D.*', ' f123456 f1234567 ')
Out[156]: ['1234567']
```

...but I'm wanting this result:

```
Out[156]: ['123456', '1234567']
```

I can't figure out how to form this regex. Can you please help?

Answer (score 8):

Simplify regex

```
In [5]: re.findall(r'\d{6,7}', ' f123456 f1234567 ')
Out[5]: ['123456', '1234567']
```